# Passing Lambda expression to a method C#

Tags: c#, delegates

Could you please suggest how can I implement the "Alexa" class?

```
var alexa = new Alexa();
        Console.WriteLine(alexa.Talk()); //print hello, i am Alexa
        alexa.Configure(x =>
        {
            x.GreetingMessage = "Hello { OwnerName}, I am at your service";
            x.OwnerName = "Bob Marley";
        });
        Console.WriteLine(alexa.Talk()); //print Hello Bob Marley, I am at your service
```

I tried to implement the method as:

```
public void Configure(Action<Configration> p)
    {
        
    }

public class Configration
{
    public string GreetingMessage { get; set; }
    public string OwnerName { get; set; }
}
```

But I can't figure out how to prin the GreetingMessage.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand how "Passing Lambda expression to a method C#" is related to suggesting how to implement a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that like so:

```
public class Alexa
{
    private Configration _configration;

    public Alexa()
    {
        _configration = new Configration
        {
            // This sets the default message you wanted.
            GreetingMessage = "Hello, I am Alexa."
        };
    }

    public void Configure(Action<Configration> configuration)
    {
        // I'll explain this below.
        configuration(_configration);
    }

    public string Talk()
    {
        return _configration.GreetingMessage;
    }
}
```

But, you do need to change how you call this to get the result you're after. When you do this:

```
alexa.Configure(x =>
{
    x.GreetingMessage = $"Hello {x.OwnerName}, I am at your service";
    x.OwnerName = "Bob Marley";
});
```

it will actually print `Hello , I am at your service` instead of the intended `Hello Bob Marley, I am at your service`. This is because `OwnerName` hasn't yet been set to `Bob Marley`. To fix that, we need to change the assignment to `OwnerName` to come before it's used in the greeting, like so:

```
alexa.Configure(x =>
{
    x.OwnerName = "Bob Marley";
    x.GreetingMessage = $"Hello {x.OwnerName}, I am at your service";
});
```

Finally, you may wonder what `configuration(_configration);` is doing. It's actually short-hand for `configuration.Invoke(_configration);`, which will execute the `Action` delegate, passing `_configration` as the `Configuration` parameter.

Calling it using the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var alexa = new Alexa();
    Console.WriteLine(alexa.Talk());
    alexa.Configure(x =>
    {
        x.OwnerName = "Bob Marley";
        x.GreetingMessage = $"Hello {x.OwnerName}, I am at your service";
    });
    Console.WriteLine(alexa.Talk());
}
```

Results in:

```
Hello, I am Alexa.
Hello Bob Marley, I am at your service
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have access to the talk method, just pass the configuration to the action. Then grab the information from the class you passed to the action.

```
public class Configration
{
    public string GreetingMessage { get; set; }
    public string OwnerName { get; set; }
}

public class Alexa()
{
    public Configration ConfigurationModel { get; set; }
    public Action<Configration> Configration { get; set; }

    public void Talk()
    {
        this.Configuration.Invoke(ConfigurationModel);
        Console.WriteLine(ConfigurationModel.GreetingMessage);
    }
}

void main()
{
    var alexa = new Alexa();
    Console.WriteLine(alexa.Talk()); //print hello, i am Alexa
    alexa.Configure(x =>
    {
        x.GreetingMessage = "Hello { OwnerName}, I am at your service";
        x.OwnerName = "Bob Marley";
    });
    Console.WriteLine(alexa.Talk()); //print Hello Bob Marley, I am at your service
}
```